# Get the biggest value in a struct matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a struct `S` of size `3x1` where `S(1,1)=[209,443,319, 206]` `S(2,1)=[300,473,1,1]` `S(3,1)=[305,470,1,1]` what I want to do is to keep only 1 internal struct where `S`  will be of size `1x1` instead of `nx1` this struct is the one that has the highest values in the 3rd and 4th column among the other structs. So in my example `S` will only have `S(1,1)` because its 3rd and 4th column are the highest among S(2,1) and S(3,1) with values 319,206 compared to 1,1 of `S(2,1)` and `S(3,1)` so `S(2,1)` and `S(3,1)` will be deleted and `S` will be `1x1` struct only having `S(1,1)`. So if anyone could please advise

Comment: You mean `cell` not `struct` I think. No fields are mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that your measure of that fact that the 3rd and 4th column are bigger then in other arrays is based on their sum.

```
  S = struct();  
  S(1,1).v=[209, 443, 319, 206];
  S(2,1).v=[300, 473, 1, 1];
  S(3,1).v=[305, 470, 1, 1];


  % find index with maxium 3th and 4th column based on their sum
  [~, ind] = max(cellfun(@(v) v(3)+v(4), {S(:).v}))

  % set S to be equal only to the value with highest 3th and 4th column
  S = S(ind);
```

Btw, syntax `S(1,1)=[209,443,319, 206]` is incorrect. Can't make structure like this. Thus I added a `v` field to structure.

In case you mean actually a `cell` rather than a `struct` as @chappjc indicated, than you can do as follows:

```
  S = {};  
  S{1,1}=[209,443,319, 206];
  S{2,1}=[300,473,1,1];
  S{3,1}=[305,470,1,1];

  [~, ind] = max(cellfun(@(v) v(3)+v(4), S));
  S = S(ind);
```